# why does the scss build fail?

Tags: webpack, sass, vue.js

In my vue-cli webpack project, I try to include mixin.scss and base.scss in my global index.scss. But it fails:

[image]

I am really confused. Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: You need to provide your webpack config and the code of the file where you require your scss.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure webpack to load `scss`. And for that you need to install `node-sass` and `sass-loader` .Use below commands to install

> npm i -S node-sass sass-loader

Add new rule to load `scss` in webpack.config file

```
module:{
  rules:[
         ...some tests
         {test:/\.scss$/,use:['style-loader','css-loader','sass-loader']}
    ]
}
```

**Note** : *loaders run in reverse so firstly sass-loader will run. So order is important*